# Does the Qur'an mention the bliss of the believing women in paradise?

Tags: women, jannah, reward

Is there any verse in the Qur'an which speaks of how women will be honoured in paradise,as Allah will honour a man with the hoor al-'een ?

Answer (score 1):

Hoor al-'een are just one example of a reward, not the only reward in paradise. In general the ayat about reward\honour in paradise are generic, equally applicable to men and women as well. Some ayat that mention women explicitly:

> And their Lord responded to them, "Never will I allow to be lost the
>   work of [any] worker among you, whether male or female; you are of one
>   another. So those who emigrated or were evicted from their homes or
>   were harmed in My cause or fought or were killed - I will surely
>   remove from them their misdeeds, and I will surely admit them to
>   gardens beneath which rivers flow as reward from Allah, and Allah has
>   with Him the best reward."([3:195](https://legacy.quran.com/3/195))
>
> And whoever does righteous deeds, whether male or female, while being
>   a believer - those will enter Paradise and will not be wronged, [even
>   as much as] the speck on a date seed.([4:124](https://legacy.quran.com/4/124))
>
> Allah has promised the believing men and believing women gardens
>   beneath which rivers flow, wherein they abide eternally, and pleasant
>   dwellings in gardens of perpetual residence; but approval from Allah
>   is greater. It is that which is the great attainment.([9:72](https://legacy.quran.com/9/72))
>
> Whoever does righteousness, whether male or female, while he is a
>   believer - We will surely cause him to live a good life, and We will
>   surely give them their reward [in the Hereafter] according to the best
>   of what they used to do.([16:97](https://legacy.quran.com/16/97))
>
> Indeed, the Muslim men and Muslim women, the believing men and
>   believing women, the obedient men and obedient women, the truthful men
>   and truthful women, the patient men and patient women, the humble men
>   and humble women, the charitable men and charitable women, the fasting
>   men and fasting women, the men who guard their private parts and the
>   women who do so, and the men who remember Allah often and the women
>   who do so - for them Allah has prepared forgiveness and a great
>   reward.([33:35](https://legacy.quran.com/33/35))
>
> Whoever does an evil deed will not be recompensed except by the like
>   thereof; but whoever does righteousness, whether male or female, while
>   he is a believer - those will enter Paradise, being given provision
>   therein without account.([40:40](https://legacy.quran.com/40/40))
>
> [And] that He may admit the believing men and the believing women to
>   gardens beneath which rivers flow to abide therein eternally and
>   remove from them their misdeeds - and ever is that, in the sight of
>   Allah, a great attainment -([48:5](https://legacy.quran.com/48/5))
>
> On the Day you see the believing men and believing women, their light
>   proceeding before them and on their right, [it will be said], "Your
>   good tidings today are [of] gardens beneath which rivers flow, wherein
>   you will abide eternally." That is what is the great
>   attainment.([57:12](https://legacy.quran.com/57/12))

Comment: Of course the  hoor- al'aeen is not the only reward in jannah,There are so many rewards for believing man and women.but i am asking this question in the perspective of this point that Allah will honour a man with hor al'aeen then what for women  ? Is the life partner of a women will become her companion in jannah ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gPrmcQ_xgY

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there are texts describing a specific reward for women the **same** way hoor are described for men. However, I also don't remember seeing anything specific promised to all men to the exclusion of women besides hoor/marriage related rewards.

I do know that there are ayat and ahadith which specify rewards in Jannah for specific women.

"And Allah presents an example of those who believed: the wife of Pharaoh, when she said, "My Lord, build for me near You a house in Paradise and save me from Pharaoh and his deeds and save me from the wrongdoing people."(66:11 translation)

Narrated Abu Huraira:
The Prophet (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) said that Gabriel said, "Here is Khadija coming to you with a dish of food or a tumbler containing something to drink. Convey to her a greeting from her Lord (Allah) and give her the glad tidings that she will have a palace in Paradise built of Qasab wherein there will be neither any noise nor any fatigue (trouble)." (See Hadith No. 168, Vol. 5)(Source of translation: sunnah.com)
Sahih al-Bukhari 7497

Narrated `Aisha:
I did not feel jealous of any of the wives of the Prophet (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam)  as much as I did of Khadija (although) she died before he married me, for I often heard him mentioning her, and Allah had told him to give her the good tidings that she would have a palace of Qasab (i.e. pipes of precious stones and pearls in Paradise), and whenever he slaughtered a sheep, he would send her women-friends a good share of it.(Source of translation: sunnah.com)
Sahih al-Bukhari 3816

Narrated `Aisha:
Once Fatima came walking and her gait resembled the gait of the Prophet(sallallahu alayhi wa sallam)  . The Prophet (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam)  said, "Welcome, O my daughter!" Then he made her sit on his right or on his left side, and then he told her a secret and she started weeping. I asked her, "Why are you weeping?" He again told her a secret and she started laughing. I said, "I never saw happiness so near to sadness as I saw today." I asked her what the Prophet(sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) had told her. She said, "I would never disclose the secret of Allah's Messenger (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) ." When the Prophet (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam)  died, I asked her about it. She replied. "The Prophet (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) said: 'Every year Gabriel used to revise the Qur'an with me once only, but this year he has done so twice. I think this portends my death, and you will be the first of my family to follow me.' So I started weeping. Then he said. 'Don't you like to be the chief of all the ladies of Paradise or the chief of the believing women? So I laughed for that."(Source of translation: sunnah.com)
Sahih al-Bukhari 3623, 3624

Women are specifically mentioned, along with men, in ahadith as well.

Al-Tirmidhi (2399) narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Trials will continue to befall the believer, man or woman, concerning himself, his child and his wealth, until he meets Allaah with no sin on him.” Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami’, no. 5815.(Source of translation: islamqa.info)

Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
Allah’s messenger (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) said, "The Mufarridun have gone ahead." He was asked, "Who are the Mufarridun?" He (sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) replied, "Those men and women who make much dhikr of Allah."

[Muslim].

Reassuring ahadith:

Umm Habiba reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said:
مَا مِنْ عَبْدٍ مُسْلِمٍ يُصَلِّي لِلَّهِ كُلَّ يَوْمٍ ثِنْتَيْ عَشْرَةَ رَكْعَةً تَطَوُّعًا غَيْرَ فَرِيضَةٍ إِلَّا بَنَى اللَّهُ لَهُ بَيْتًا فِي الْجَنَّةِ أَوْ إِلَّا بُنِيَ لَهُ بَيْتٌ فِي الْجَنَّةِ
There is no Muslim servant who prays for Allah twelve bowings every day in addition to what is obligatory except that Allah will build for him a house in Paradise.
Umm Habiba said:
فَمَا بَرِحْتُ أُصَلِّيهِنَّ بَعْدُ
I have never abandoned praying them after this.
Source: Sahih Muslim 728, Grade: Sahih
In another narration, the Prophet(sallallahu alayhi wa sallam) said:
مَنْ صَلَّى فِي يَوْمٍ وَلَيْلَةٍ ثِنْتَيْ عَشْرَةَ رَكْعَةً بُنِيَ لَهُ بَيْتٌ فِي الْجَنَّةِ أَرْبَعًا قَبْلَ الظُّهْرِ وَرَكْعَتَيْنِ بَعْدَهَا وَرَكْعَتَيْنِ بَعْدَ الْمَغْرِبِ وَرَكْعَتَيْنِ بَعْدَ الْعِشَاءِ وَرَكْعَتَيْنِ قَبْلَ صَلَاةِ الْفَجْرِ
Whoever prays twelve additional bowings in a day and night will have a house built for him in Paradise: four before noon prayer and two after it, two after sunset prayer, two after evening prayer, and two before dawn prayer.
Source: Sunan At-Tirmidhi 415, Grade: Sahih

In the Qur’an, Allah mentions multiple times that females specifically will be rewarded in the hereafter. The male plural in Arabic can encompass females in meaning, yet Allah still specified Muslim females separately from males, as being destined for reward. Examples:

“If any do deeds of righteousness, be they male or female, and have faith, they will enter Jannah, and not the least injustice will be done to them.” (Surah an-Nisa:124)

Gardens of perpetual bliss: they shall enter there, as well as the righteous among their fathers, their spouses, and their offspring.” (Surah ar-Ra`d: 23)

“Enter the Garden, you and your wives, you will be made glad. There will be brought round for them trays of gold and goblets, and therein is all that the souls desire and eyes find sweet and you will stay there forever. This is the garden, which you are made to inherit because of what you used to do. Therein for you is fruit in plenty whence to eat.” (Az-Zukhruf 43:70-73)

“Indeed, the people of Paradise will be happily occupied. They and their wives shall be in shades, reclining on raised couches. There are for them fruits and there is for them all that they ask for...”(Ya-Sin 36: 55-57)

“Allah has promised the believing men and believing women gardens beneath which rivers flow, wherein they abide eternally, and pleasant dwellings in gardens of perpetual residence; but approval from Allah is greater. It is that which is the great attainment.”(9:72)

“[And] that He may admit the believing men and the believing women to gardens beneath which rivers flow to abide therein eternally and remove from them their misdeeds - and ever is that, in the sight of Allah, a great attainment”(48:5)

“Indeed, the Muslim men and Muslim women, the believing men and believing women, the obedient men and obedient women, the truthful men and truthful women, the patient men and patient women, the humble men and humble women, the charitable men and charitable women, the fasting men and fasting women, the men who guard their private parts and the women who do so, and the men who remember Allah often and the women who do so - for them Allah has prepared forgiveness and a great reward.”( 33:35)

"And their Lord responded to them, 'Never will I allow to be lost the work of [any] worker among you, whether male or female; you are of one another. So those who emigrated or were evicted from their homes or were harmed in My cause or fought or were killed - I will surely remove from them their misdeeds, and I will surely admit them to gardens beneath which rivers flow as reward from Allah , and Allah has with Him the best reward.'" [Âli `Imrân: 195]

Commenting on the aforementioned verse, Ibn Kathîr (may Allah have mercy on him) said, "Allah has told people that He will never allow the work of any worker among them to be lost; rather, He will give the due reward to every worker, whether male or female. The statement: 'you are of one another' means that both men and women are equal in terms of the reward of Allah the Almighty."

“Whoever does righteousness, whether male or female, while he is a believer - We will surely cause him to live a good life, and We will surely give them their reward [in the Hereafter] according to the best of what they used to do.”( 16:97)

"On the Day you see the believing men and believing women, their light proceeding before them and on their right, [it will be said], "Your good tidings today are [of] gardens beneath which rivers flow, wherein you will abide eternally." That is what is the great attainment." (57:12)

Um Umarah al-Ansariyyah said that she went to the Prophet (May peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) and said to Him: "I feel that everything is for men. Women are not mentioned as having anything. Then was revealed the Verse: (For Muslim men and women, for believing men and women etc), Verse 35, Surat al-Ahzab, or the Confederates. The Hadith is narrated by at-Tirmidhi under No. 3211, and is in Sahih at-Tirmidhi under No. 2565.(Source of translation: islamqa)

Some texts on the pleasures of Jannah:

“We [angels] were your allies in worldly life and [are so] in the Hereafter. And you will have therein whatever your souls desire, and you will have therein whatever you request [or wish]
As accommodation from a [Lord who is] Forgiving and Merciful." ”(Qur’an 41:31-32)

It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Allaah says: ‘I have prepared for My righteous slaves that which no eye has seen, no ear has heard and it has never crossed the mind of man. All of that is reserved, besides which all that you have known is as nothing.’
Then he recited: ‘No person knows what is kept hidden for them of joy as a reward for what they used to do’ [al-Sajdah 32:17 – interpretation of the meaning].” (Source of translation: islamqa)

Narrated by al-Bukhaari (3072) and Muslim (2824) -- the report narrated by Muslim adds: “apart from that of which Allaah has informed you.”

Al-Mugheerah ibn Shu‘bah said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Moosa asked his Lord: ‘Who will be the lowest of the people of Paradise in status?’ He said: ‘He will be a man who will come after I have admitted the people of Paradise to Paradise and it will be said to him: “Enter Paradise.” He will say: “O Lord, how, when the people have taken their places and been given their portions?” It will be said to him: “Would it please you if you had the like of what one of the kings of the world had?” He will say: “I would be pleased, O Lord.” He will say, “You will have that, and as much again, and as much again, and as much again, and as much again.” The fifth time, he will say, “I am pleased, O Lord.” He will say: “You will have that and ten times as much, and you will have what your heart desires and what will delight your eyes.” He will say: “I am pleased, O Lord.”’ (Moosa) said: ‘My Lord, who will be the highest of them in status?’ He said, ‘They will be the ones whom I have chosen, and I have planted their honour with My own hand. I have set a seal over it and no eye has seen, no ear has heard, nor has it entered the heart of man.’” He said: And the confirmation thereof is in the Book of Allaah, may He be glorified and exalted: “No person knows what is kept hidden for them of joy as a reward for what they used to do” [al-Sajdah 32:17]. 
Narrated by Muslim, 189. (Source of translation: islamqa)

Disclaimer: As with all my answers, I am not giving a fatwa. I share what I know of Islamic scripture, historical events and words of scholars, and translations of them, and sometimes my opinion, and they may or may not be the correct answer to the question, based on whether or not I interpreted them correctly as being relevant. Scriptural texts posted in English are a translation from the original Arabic and may not encompass the full meaning of the original.